# Align long text at the right and bottom of the imageview android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an `activity` in my `android` app in which I want to show complete blog. Blog has 2 things which are image and the description and the latter gets very long at times depending what the user writes. Both image and description are coming from the server. Now I want to design my activity like the attached image and I don't know if this can be done from `xml` or `java`.
[image]

I tried using `RelativeLayout` in my `activity` like below but it does not cover the space below the `ImageView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    tools:context=".PostDetailsActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/postImg"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/postImg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/test" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the picture, you are having 2 text boxes. In the layout, you are having only 1. How this could possibly be working? Android views are rectangular. You can't shape them in random ways or shape the text in a random way.

Your title is just wrong. You are saying:

Align long text at the right and bottom of the imageview android

But actually, it should be:

"How to align a text inside a TextView in a random shape."

Just try to figure out new design with 2 TextViews. See what can fit in the first TextView and put the rest of the text in the other TextView. Maybe you can make them look like only one.